# TFS Scrum - if bugs and PBIs are treated on same level, shouldn't their work item states be the same?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We are using the scrum template for TFS 2013. Product Backlog Items and Bugs are at the same 'level', so they are both viewed on the backlog and tasks are created as children underneath. Why do PBIs have the states: New, Approved, Committed, Done, Removed, while Bugs have the states: New, In Progress, Done, Closed (which is the same as tasks)?

By treating PBIs and Bugs essentially the same, I would expect that they should have the same states. I'm not sure what 'Done' is supposed to mean as opposed to 'Closed'. I find it confusing that tasks and bugs can be marked 'Done', which is not the same as a PBI marked 'Done'.

I want to change the names of the states for the the PBIs, bugs, and/or tasks to use more consistent naming conventions, but I think I may be misunderstanding what the terms mean.

Comment: Has your Scrum process template been customized?

Answer (score 2):

As Cece mentioned, the out of the box states in Scrum between PBI and Bug are similar. You can use [witadmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) to change the states of your Bug work item type to match PBIs.

Another option is to use the [Kanban board](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/work/kanban/kanban-basics), where you can create a set of columns and map each column to a state of each work item type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your Scrum Process Template has been customized before. In the default Scrum process template of TFS 2013, PBI and Bug do have the same states: **New, Approved, Committed, Done, Removed**, while Task has the states: **To Do, In Progress, Done, Removed**.

The following diagrams show the typical forward progression of PBI, Bug, and Task work items used to track work and code defects for TFS default Scrum process templates:

**PBI:**

[image]

**Bug:**

[image]

**Task:**

[image]

Comment: I guess it has been customized then! I'm kind of taking over and there isn't really a record of what was done previously. I'll try to change the names and transitions back to what they were before. Will the current states of all of the currently existing bugs get completely lost though?

Comment: Existing bugs won't be lost. But you will get warnings when you open the existing bugs, like "The field "State" contains the value "In Process" that is not in the list of supported values".

Comment: Thanks! Hmm it looks like the bugs and tasks were possibly further modified. None of the diagrams above show the state "Closed", which is a state after "Done" in my configuration for Tasks and Bugs. Maybe I should just remove "Closed" while I'm at it?

Comment: I'd like to suggest you make a copy of "Bug" and "Task" work item types to do the modification, so that you can validate the transition before putting it into production. You can remove the "Closed" state if you don't need it anymore, just make sure the transition will be set to what you want.